# Good 3D , OpenGL engine to work with .dae (Collada) objects in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, collada

I've been using NinevehGL 3D engine in my present project, but it no longer support iOS 6, iOS 7 (I cant take screenshot,in iOS 7 device it simply disappear ).

The project specifically is:-

"It is 3D sofa builder. I have .dae files of each part of sofa. 3D engine just selects particular part of sofa (.dae) objects and attach it with sofa. User could change colors or shades of sofa as well also use can rotate it into 3D space "

So i have done bit of research and found Unity 3D engine. I learned that it is compatible with .dae objects but its expensive also it is for creating complex games rather then simple 3D interface which required in my project (description given above).

I checked Cocoa 3D also, not sure it support .dae files?

if somebody has experience using other engines or these above ones and suggest me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You do realize Unity has a free version? Other than that, this is a recommendation question. Those are off-topic on the site.

Comment: It may be a recommendation question but it will helpful for others searching same top as me. Hope it make sense

Comment: Unfortunately they are a no-go on the site. You can find various discussions on the topic on http://meta.stackoverflow.com . Perhaps http://slant.co might be a better fit?